# How to create an index-file for Xampp

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

I apologize in advance if this issue has been posted before. My problem is that my programmer had to bail on my project due to personal reasons and left me alone with a 95% finished site. I have some basic experience with ASP classic but PHP is fairly new to me.

FireFTP scr_shot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9lws1u0sl8k93rg/fireftp_scr_shot.jpg

To shorten it up; (with Xampp installed) I have downloaded my site to the hard-drive and is now trying to get it work on 'localhost'. Immediately I sense the absence of an index-file.

Do I need to make one myself for the use in localhost? In that case, what am I looking for?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: no, index file is not highly required in xampp, its only redirect us to xampp folder.it will not effect to xampp performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was a MYSQL-database behind the site which I had no idea about or any knowledge of how to get around.

I had the database taken off and written the code into the site-files.

Afterwards everything worked as laid out above comments.

Answer (score 0):

First if you want to make an index-file of your current website, you have to put all your pages in a folder in

> xampp/htdocs/

e.g

> C:\Xampp\htdocs\mywebsite

then after you make a directory just visit the url like this:

> localhost/mywebsite

, remember to put an index file inside the mywebsite folder.

Comment: Hi Cedric. That's all done OK :) . My issue is the index file itself. What code should i write in it? Should it be an index.php or index.html?? Thx in advance!

Comment: if you are coding with no server side on it (php) then name it to index.html, just follow a simple code for html so you can put some content on your page like this: 


`<html><head><title>Sample website</title></head><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>`

Comment: That I understand. The point is that I already have the above mentioned site: http://sukhumvithd.com Now I need it to work locally. I only see these 3 folders > https://www.dropbox.com/s/9lws1u0sl8k93rg/fireftp_scr_shot.jpg What should the index-file look like then?

Comment: if you already started the XAMPP and downloaded the above mentioned site in your htdocs directory, open your browser then type this one: `localhost/<name_of_directory>` or this one: `localhost/<name_of_directory/index.html>` name of directory is the folder where your index is located. It will now run locally if you visit that URL.